# Unable to have webEnvironment and repository access in the same Spring Boot Integration Test

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, integration-testing, junit5, spring-test

**Notes on the solution:**

@Transactional annotation and using lazy loading repository access seems to have been the root cause.

**Context:**

I'm writing Junit5 integration tests for a SpringBoot application (v2.2.5.RELEASE). It would start up SpringBoot with a webEnvironment, call each rest endpoint and assert the results.

Since we have a cache layer between our service and persistence layers I also injected the repository to directly check the database contents as well.

**Problem:**

It seems that I can access the database directly through the injected repository or through the web call that eventually **calls the same repository** (not sure if it calls the same instance though, with all the SpringBootTest magic going on in the background).

When I try to call both in the same test case whichever comes first runs properly and the second fails spectacularly.

**Case A**: Web endpoint access followed by a direct repository access

- Web endpoint uses the database, creates the resource (confirmed by a separate db query)
- Direct repository access does not find any entity even though its clearly in the db

**Case B**: Direct repository access followed by a web endpoint access

- Direct repository access creates the resource (confirmed by a separate db query)
- Web endpoint does not find any entity even though its clearly in the db

```java
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles("it")
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = SecurityAutoConfiguration.class)
@Sql(scripts = {"classpath:schema_init.sql"})
@Transactional
public class ClientIntegrationTest {

    // This is the same repository class that is at the end of the api call
    @Autowired
    private ClientRepository repository;


    // CASE A

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Create a new client")
    @Sql(scripts = "classpath:data_int.sql")
    void createNewClientTest() {
        // given
        Client rawClient = new Client("testdetails");

        // when
        Client savedClient =  Unirest
                .post("myendpoint_save")
                .body(rawClient)
                .asObject(Client.class)
                .getBody();

        // then
        assertThat(repository.findById(savedClient.getId()).get())
                .as("The DB state is the same as the returned state")
                .isEqualTo(savedClient);
    }


    // CASE B

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Get client by id")
    @Sql(scripts = "classpath:data_int.sql")
    void getClientByIdTest() {
        // given
        Client savedEntity = repository.save(new Client("testdetails"));

        // when
        Client retrievedClient = Unirest
                .post("myendpoint_getbyid")
                .queryString("clientId", savedEntity.getId())
                .asObject(Client.class)
                .getBody();

        // then
        // omitted assertions
    }

}
```

I assume that the source of the problem might be related to the webEnvironment running in a separate thread, but even that makes no sense as the database is the single source of truth in both operations.

So why does the **same repository** have different results when looking at **the same db state** 
within the **same test case** directly and through a web call?

Comment: Another idea: @Transactional only works for direct repository access since transactions are usually Thread-bound. Have you tried wi5hout @Transactional?

Comment: @johanneslink thanks, that might be a step in the right direction as it has solved part of the problem and revealed new details that might help to find the root cause. I'll update the desciption

Comment: Just for the record there were two other things that led me believe that removing Transactional would not solve the problem:
- I was missing a manual cache reset step after adding an entity to the DB (silly me)
- In another test case instead of findById() that works with eager loading I was using getOne() that is lazy loading and I got a session not found error.

@johanneslink could you create an answer, so that I can mark it as the solution? thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing `@Transactional` could solve your problem.

`@Transactional` is meant to control transactional behaviour in direct repository access only.